# Should I use “was” or “were”?

Tags: grammar

> One of the successful managers **were** asked

or

> One of the successful managers **was** asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/01/) has this example which is almost identical to OP's case:

> One of the boxes *is* open.

The verb agrees with the subject, "One". If you wanted to talk about "two", you would use a plural verb:

> Two of the successful managers **were** asked.
>
> One of the successful managers **was** asked.

Comment: Yes, those sentences are standard.